# Running Queries Stats

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I need to get below information of MySql workbench queries:

1. When the querying started ?
2. When it finished ?
3. The duration of query ?
4. which Query stop after error ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MySQL Server with version >= 5.6 you can have a look  on Performance Reports which can give you many informations on MySQL queries (and not specifically Workbench Queries).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @SkaJess. 
I am using 6.3 version. Actually I need to create an alert (in email) 
which show the stats.
So i need queries to show the above information.